# How to set static property and read from parent

Tags: c#, activerecord, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android

What I want to achieve is this

```
// Base class
public Class ActiveRecord {
   public static string CollectionName;

   public static Collection() {
       return CollectionInstance(CollectionName); // just pseudo code
   }
}

// Child class
public Class Post : ActiveRecord
{
   public static string CollectionName = "posts"; 
}
```

I know that php AR works in this way (maybe in ruby to) but don't know how to achieve this in C# or there is another approach to achieve this?

Comment: Not with static. You can do it with instance properties though.

Comment: What do you recommend if don't want to instantiate a model to query it, just like AR does, if there is no other way I will try your solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with static fields or static constructors. Note that in C#, the order of execution of static constructors is [not under your control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx):

> The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in the program.

So you have no guarantee that the derived constructor will execute first and set the CollectioName.

Also, what you're trying to do is not possible, since base constructors are executed first, before any derived constructors are called.

Further, you cannot return anything from constructor, so this statement is invalid:

```
return CollectionInstance(CollectionName); // just pseudo code
```

What you can do is this:

```
// Base class
public class ActiveRecord {

   public ActiveRecord(string name) {
       CollectionInstance = new CollectionInstance(name); // just pseudo code
   }
}

// Child class
public class Post : ActiveRecord
{
   public Post(): base("posts"){}
}
```

or this:

```
// Child class
public class Post : ActiveRecord
{  
   private static readonly string CollectionName = "posts";
   public Post(): base(CollectionName){}
}
```

Comment: But this only will work if Post is initialized? Like Post post = new Post();

Because AR used static methods Post.Find()

Comment: There is no point in deriving from static classes. What you may try is the [Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx#lazy) pattern. In your case, `Posts.Find()` will use the `Instance` or `Collection` to do its work.

Answer (score 0):

From mu understanding, you cannot override a static property in c#.

If you want to override it, you will need to change it to an instance property and then it can be overridden.

```
// Base class
public Class ActiveRecord {
   public virtual string CollectionName {get;}

   public static Collection() {
       return CollectionInstance(CollectionName); // just pseudo code
   }
}

// Child class
public Class Post : ActiveRecord
{
   public override string CollectionName { get{ return "posts";}}
}
```

Comment: No such thing as virtual fields in C#.

Comment: @Mrchief yes, the code was an error, if you read my answer, I am talking about properties

Comment: That's what I was hoping. You still have invalid code though.